# Nodejs module files and concat

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, gulp, gulp-concat

I've been looking at nodejs and how to create and require modules. Makes sense and works great.

I am interested though in using a concat function gulp-concat at the moment to concat all the js files into one js file.

This got me thinking that it is not possible when setting up a modular environment as when using the require function requires the modules to be in other files.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this? Are the files supposed to be in separate files?

Comment: Are you looking for something like requirejs - r.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is typically run on the server side or as a desktop process. Unlike JavaScript running in the browser where concatenating files has advantages, Node.js has no need for this. Similar to Java or C# applications, separating classes/modules into files makes managing the code easier and more maintainable.

[gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) is most likely being used as a tool by developers to concatenate arbitrary JavaScript files that will eventually end up in the browser.